# I want to avoid id duplication and add values using push

Tags: javascript

controller
$scope.items = [
      {"id" : 1 , "itemname" : "name_1", "comment" : "dsdsd", "price" : 5000},
      {"id" : 1 , "itemname" : "name_2", "comment" : "dddd", "price": 3000},
      {"id" : 3 , "itemname" : "name_3", "comment" : "sdasd", "price" : 2000},
      {"id" : 4 , "itemname" : "name_4", "comment" : "asdasd", "price" : 3000},
      {"id" : 5 , "itemname" : "name_5", "comment" : "asdasd", "price" : 2000}
    ]

$scope.addToCart=function(item){
cart.add(item);
}

service
    cartObj.cart.add=function(item){
      cartObj.cart.push(item);
    };

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cart">
<div>id: {{item.id}}</div>
<div>itemname: {{item.itemname}}</div>
</div>
```

top code cart.html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<a ng-click="addToCart(item)">[ addcart ]</a>
</div>
```

top code index.html

Example OUTPUT
id   1
   name_1    5000
   name_2    3000
id   3
   name_3    2000
id   4
   name_4    3000
id   5
   name_5    2000

Comment: Where do these duplicates come from? Neither `cartObj.cart.add` nor `$scope.addToCart` do push items into `$scope.items`. And where is the ID added to the `item` you push to `$scope.items`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check wether there's already an item with that id, before pushing.

```
let oldItem = $scope.items.find(elm => elm.id === item.id);
if(oldItem){
    //you can assign the properties of `item` to the one in the list
    Object.assign(oldItem, item);
}else{
    $scope.items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not solved. Any problems ...
Please look at the code again

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's safe to push to an array before pushing on to it.

```
if ($scope.items.indexOf(item) == -1) {
   $scope.items.push(item);
}
```